# Sencha Ext JS run time license

Tags: licensing, runtime, extjs

Do you need to buy a run time license from Sencha if your application code written is developed in Ext JS and deployed on a web server?

http://www.sencha.com

Comment: Just save yourself the hassle and choose a different framework.

Comment: @pllee, care to tell us why it is a hassle?

Comment: @EmmadKareem I would but I don't think this is the best place.  You can see my contact info in my profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your server app is open source, no... I.e. you give the code away freely

If you don't want to give the code away, you need a license per developer working on the site.

Comment: So if it was commercialized software application using Sencha Ext JS, and we had 5 developers who are currently developing the application and 10,000 users connecting to the production web server hosting the application, we would only need to buy licenses for 5 developers?

Comment: Yes, 5 licenses

Comment: Would you need to share your server side code too? For example would I need to share the NodeJS routes that are implemented for the ajax-api that the Ext JS application is using?

Comment: As far as I understand it, yes, you would need to share the server side code too.